# Why does my MongoDB bulk remove not work?

Tags: mongodb

I am following [this](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/method/Bulk.find.remove/) documentation but somehow it does not work.
Given the same docs I was able to do a bulk update, but the remove somehow does not work.

```
        var bulk = db.collection('item').initializeUnorderedBulkOp()
        for(let i = 0; i < ids.length; i++){
            console.log(ids[i])
            bulk.find( ({ 'itemArray.id': ids[i] } )).remove()
        }
        return await bulk.execute()
```

ids is an array of ids which are meant to be deleted.

All I get is:

```
Error: bulk.find(...).remove is not a function
```

and I am not sure how to fix it, since I am doing it as they tell me to

Comment: are you running it via mongo shell? or in javascript

Comment: @Tom javascript

Comment: Experiencing this too. It's something with the new node mongo driver and changes they made. But I can't find anything about this in the change docs.

Comment: Also instead of looping, you could just use a single find like `bulk.find({'itemArray.id': {$in: ids}}).remove()`. That works. Well at least on the old node mongo driver.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using a new javascript driver (such as [mongodb](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongodb) v4.x), you'll need to switch to `bulk.find(...).delete()`.

This is documented here: https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/4.5/classes/OrderedBulkOperation.html#find

Unfortunately, it does not appear to be included in the migration guide from v3.x.